# JQuery tooltip not working using Jquery template. Need help

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates, jquery-tooltip

If my link is outside the template than tooltip is working fine but if its in JQuery template not working at all. Tried many examples but no success.

Below is the code

**In Js file after grid is loaded**

```
ReloadGrid();

$(".hello").tooltip({
    track: true,
    delay: 0,
    showURL: false,
    fade: 250,
    bodyHandler: function () {
        return $($(this).next().html());
    },
    showURL: false
});
```

**On Page**

```
<script id="cellTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <tr  class="gridRowCursor"  >
        <td class="cellTd ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCb" />
            <input type="hidden" id="Id_ + ${Id}" class="idField" value="${Id}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">
            <input id="index" name="index" class="numberField" type="text" value="${IndexOrder}" />
        </td>
        <td  class="cellTdLeft" style="font-size:11px;">

            <a class="hello"  href="#">{{html DisplayName}}</a>

          <div id="tooltip" style="display: none">
                <div>
                   {{html UrlName}}
                </div>
            </div>



        </td>
        <td class="cellTd ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="activeCb" {{if Active}} checked{{/if}} />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="${Id}" class="gridRow" style="display: none;">
        <td class="cellTdLeft" colspan="5" style="padding-left: 15px; font-size:11px;">
            {{html UrlName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>   


<span class="instructions">Only numeric value is allowed in IndexOrder textbox.</span>
<div class="gridDiv">
<table id="set1" class="gridTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
    <thead>
        <tr class="gridTitleRow">
            <td class="iconLink width36">Delete</td>
            <td class="iconLink width60">Sort Order</td>
            <td class="iconLink width500">Display Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Active</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Use Live like below. Not working?

```
$(".hello").live("tooltip", function() {
     track: true,
delay: 0,
showURL: false,
fade: 250,
bodyHandler: function () {
    return $($(this).next().html());
},
showURL: false

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try $(".hello").live("tooltip", function(){  instead of $(".hello").tooltip({

Since your hello class element is not a part of the dom when it is loaded, your code is probably trying to wire up something that doesn't exist yet.  The live method will ensure that all future elements with class hello will get the tooltip event added to it.

Comment: I have edit my question using your suggestion. Is that right? . Tooltip not supporting that. Can you post full tooltip code with your suggestion please.